# tensors and pseudovectors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

If two *vectors* are related as $\vec{a}=T\vec{b}$, then $T$ is a (1,1)-type tensor so that $a^i=T_j^ib^j$.

My question is, if $\vec{c}=R\vec{d}$ is a relation between *pseudovectors* instead of vectors, for example the relation between angular momentum and angular velocity, then is $R$ also a  (1,1)-type tensor, or something else?